# Is it a good practice to use the kotlin delay() method inside a fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I need to wait a time (like 5 seconds) to execute a function inside a fragment, what is the best way to do this?

Currently i use the delay() method, i did not have problem with this method, but this does not seem like a good ideia.

Comment: Why doesn't it seem like a good idea? Are you launching it inside `viewLifecycle.lifecycleScope`?

Comment: Why do you need to wait?

Comment: To me this seems to be the responsibility of viewModel and viewModelScope and I wasn't using viewLifecycle.lifecycleScope @Tenfour04

Comment: It's like a timer to call an api again @cutiko

Comment: Then whatever you are doing, you don't need the delay, do whatever you want after the HTTP request finishes

Comment: Yes, if you're using it to wait for a result, that is quite terrible. Would have to see how you're actually using it to understand for sure if there's a problem. `delay()` in a fragment is totally appropriate if it has to do with UI appearances.

Comment: It is only used to update UI apparences. Basically I have an async back-end so i need to call an API on a time interval to check the new process state to update the UI based on it.

Comment: Yeah, `delay()` is fine for that.